# Unity Application Block: Exception occurred while resolving: BadImageFormatException

Tags: exception, unity-container, badimageformatexception

I'm using Unity 2.1 in my application and receive the error in the title for one resolving scenario. I have no idea on where to look.

- I'm running Windows 7 64bit
- 32-bit applications are **enabled**
- Tried building against "Any CPU" *and* "x64"

**The problem doesn't seem to be related to the 64bit architecture. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!**

## Scenario's

```
//works: class = "ProductManager<Product>
Container.Resolve<IProductManager<Product>>()

//works: class = "OrderManager"
Container.Resolve<IOrderManager()

//works: class="OrderManager" 
Container.Resolve<IOrderManager("OrderManager")

//DOESN'T WORK: EXCEPTION: BadImageFormatException
Container.Resolve<IOrderManager("OrderManager") 

//works: class="GenericOrderManager<Order>" (obviously)
var manager = new GenericOrderManager<Order>();
```

## Code

**Unity.config**

```
<alias name="IProductManager" type="Assembly1.Namespace.IProductManager`1" />
<alias name="ProductManager" type="Assembly2.Namespace.ProductManager`1" />

<alias name="IOrderManager" type="Assembly1.Namespace.IOrderManager" />
<alias name="OrderManager" 
       type="Assembly1.Namespace.OrderManager" />
<alias name="OrderManager" 
       type="Assembly1.Namespace.OrderManager" 
       name="OrderManager" />
<alias name="GenericOrderManager" 
       type="Assembly2.Namespace.GenericOrderManager`1"
       name="GenericOrderManager" />
```

**ProductManager + Interface**

```
public interface IProductManager<TProduct> where TProduct : Product
{
}

public class ProductManager<TProduct> : IProductManager<TProduct> where TProduct : Product
{
}
```

**OrderManager + Interface**

```
public interface IOrderManager
{
}

public class OrderManager : IOrderManager
{
}

public class OrderManager<TOrder> : OrderManager where TOrder : Order
{
}
```

**Update with StackTrace:**

> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers._CompileMethod(IRuntimeMethodInfo
>   method)    at System.Reflection.Emit.DynamicMethod.CreateDelegate(Type
>   delegateType)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext.GetBuildMethod()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext
>   context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at
>   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext
>   context)    at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type
>   t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides)

Comment: please post the completed StackTrace of the BadImageFormatException

Comment: @Jehof: Added stacktrace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Unity` version you have is `x32`. Your project assemblies are being built as `x64`, but have the 32-bit Unity assemblies as references. Unfortunately, the compile will go fine. You will get a nasty surprise at run-time, though. Bottom line: compile with platform target of `x86`.

64-bit assemblies calling 32-bit assemblies is one of the most common reasons for `BadImageFormatException`.

MSDN notes:

> A DLL or executable is loaded as a 64-bit assembly, but it contains
>   32-bit features or resources. For example, it relies on COM interop or
>   calls methods in a 32-bit dynamic link library.
>
> To address this exception, set the project's Platform target property
>   to x86 (instead of x64 or AnyCPU) and recompile.

More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.badimageformatexception.aspx).

Comment: Unity is provided with the module I'm using so I cannot rebuild it. However I have 32bit applications enabled so that shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: Then you should strictly target `x86`. You won't be able to compile x64 assemblies while using that version of Unity.

Comment: But this did work before. I need to mention maybe that I started generalizing `OrderManager` classes this morning which made the error occur...

Comment: Try and set the `x86` target, and see if that works. I believe you won't encounter the `BadImageFormatException` until runtime, meaning when the first reference to Unity actually forces the assembly resolution. That might not have been happening until now.

Comment: The reference is correct, but at runtime won't load. The reason being, a 64-bit assembly expects a 64-bit referenced assembly, not a 32-bit referenced assembly. This doesn't get resolved during design and compile - only becomes an issue at runtime, during the assembly resolution phase. I'll stop adding any further comments at this point until you try out what MSDN suggests.